# Unity: Testing multiplayer with docker

Tags: docker, unity-game-engine, kubernetes, testing, automation

I'm currently building a multiplayer game in unity, I was wondering if it's possible to create instances of 'client' with dockerfile + unity.

my plan is to :

1. host the server somewhere
2. create pods at docker to 'act' as 10+ players.

My prior experience as a programmer leads me to selenium, but I want to know is there any best practice for unity.

My previous plan is to use python to emulate clicking, keystrokes, etc. but I find that troublesome as I'll need a huge container size for that. (installing windows on the docker + the game)

my second option is to use unity's build in test case but it seems to be limited to 2 (from what I read)

any suggestions is open :D

Comment: A Docker container wraps a single process, not a full simulated computing environment, and it doesn't have simulated hardware like a VM would.  So there's nothing to "click" or "type" in.

Comment: Has your issue been resolved ? Did the David Maze comment help you?